# How can I do to return a array with dict inside?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I have this code using React.js :

```
const array1 = [1, 4];

const map1 = array1.map(x =>{'x2': x * 2, 'x3': x * 3});

console.log(map1);
// expected output: Array [{'x2': , 1, 'x3': 1}, {'x2': 8, 'x3': 24}]
```

But it does not work ... could you help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missing parentheses around your object:

```
const map1 = array1.map(x => ({ 'x2': x * 2, 'x3': x * 3 }));
```